# Entity Framework with Nullable Guid? causing Validation Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to use `Nullable` `Guid` in Entity Framework but when i tried to commit the change i am getting validation message due to foreign key is null, I have below domain class, `DomainType` Class has child `DomainCustomField` :-

## DomainType.cs

```
public class DomainType
{
    public Guid? Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    private IList<DomainCustomField> _domainCustomFields;

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Guid? AccountId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual IList<DomainCustomField> DomainCustomFields
    {
        get
        {
            return this._domainCustomFields;
        }
        set
        {
            this._domainCustomFields = value;
        }
    }
}
```

## DomainCustomField.cs

```
public class DomainCustomField 
{
        public Guid? Id
        {
                get;
                set;
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public Guid? DomainTypeId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
}
```

below is mapping :-

```
modelBuilder.Domain<DomainCustomField>().HasKey((DomainCustomField p) => new
            {
                p.Id,
                p.DomainTypeId
            });
            modelBuilder.Domain<DomainCustomField>()
                .Property(p => p.Id)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            modelBuilder.Domain<DomainType>()
                .HasMany(p => p.DomainCustomFields)
                .WithRequired()
                .HasForeignKey<Guid?>(x => x.DomainTypeId);
```

below is sample code which i tried to insert.

```
 DomainType domainType = new DomainType()
        {
            AccountId = customer.Id
        };
        domainType.DomainCustomFields.Add(new DomainCustomField()
        {
            Name = "Test"
        });
        Workspace.Add<DomainType>(domainType);
        Workspace.CommitChanges();
```

Error :- validation error for DomainTypeId is required

in the same code if i change `Guid?` to `Guid` in ID variable then its work correctly. I don't know how to handle `nullable` `Guid`. do i need to manually set parent key in child reference? then how it works fine in case of `Guid`?

Note :- I am using using `Guid` because i am working with distributed database, where id can generate from multiple source system. 
I am using `Guid?` because by default `Guid` generate `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` for empty `Guid` which can grow database size.

Comment: Did you try (add navigational property `DomainType` in the model)`.HasOptional` -> `modelBuilder.Domain<DomainCustomField>()
                .Property(p => p.Id)..HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).HasOptional(p=>p.DomainType)..HasForeignKey(x => x.DomainTypeId)`

Comment: yes i have tried HasOptional. its not that issue. its not setting parent id in child variable even though they are linked.

Comment: That error makes sense for me, may be Im totally wrong here. When your primary key is "nullable" (not sure how "nullable" primary key works), the EF might not be setting proper relation for the child collection (as the parent id is null).

Comment: The primary key cannot be null. The foreign key can; this indicates the absence of a matching row in the foreign table. Both `Id` properties need to be non-nullable. `DomainTypeId` should remain as nullable. `WithRequired` needs to change to `HasOptional`.

Answer (score 2):

The issue has nothing to do with `Guid` type (the same will happen with `int`), but the discrepancy between the nullability of the property type used in the entity and the actual nullability of the property implied by the model.

First, EF requires PKs to be non nullable. Hence `DomainType.Id`, `DomainCustomField.Id` and `DomainCustomField.DomainTypeId` are effectively non nulable (it's unclear why you have include `DomainTypeId` in the PK of the `DomainCustomField` which already have unique database generated `Id`, but that's another story).

Second, `DomainCustomField.DomainTypeId` is effectively non nullable because you have specified that - the `WithRequired()` part of the FK relationship configuration.

Now, EF does its best to handle these discrepancies. If you look at the generated migration, you will see that the corresponding database table columns of all the fields in question are non nullable. However (nothing is perfect, you know) some part of the EF code is failing to handle that discrepancy and hence the exception.

With that being said, always keep the model properties nullability in sync with their actual nullability. Which in you case is to make both 3 properties non nullable (i.e. of type `Guid`).

P.S. What about the note *I am using `Guid?` because by default `Guid` generate `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` for empty `Guid` which can grow database size.*, I have no idea what do you mean by that. The nullablitity of the class property has nothing to do with the database size, and as I already mentioned, the corresponding database table columns for such setup are non nullable anyway.

Also note that in your example you forget to set the `Id` of the new `DomainType`, which you should because it's not auto generated.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a slightly different approach in my answer and try and tell you what to change in order to get a working example;

Like someone has pointed out, unique identifiers must not be nullable so the `Id` field in `DomainType` should a `Guid`. Also you will need to change the Id field in `DomainCustomField`. These may need an empty constructor just to create a new Guid.

Secondly, the foreign key in your other object `Guid?  DomainTypeId` is perfectly fine, this can stay, but if it is staying you will need to change your configuration.

In this block you have specified that the property is required?

```
modelBuilder.Domain<DomainType>()
                .HasMany(p => p.DomainCustomFields)
                .WithRequired()
                .HasForeignKey<Guid?>(x => x.DomainTypeId);
```

So simply make it optional;

```
modelBuilder.Domain<DomainType>()
                .HasMany(p => p.DomainCustomFields)
                .WithOptional()
                .HasForeignKey<Guid?>(x => x.DomainTypeId);
```

That should solve your issues. Any questions let me know :)

Comment: This was my problem just today, I had specified the Guid column as optional but didn't do it for the has many line as above, reminding me to set it to WithOptional fixed this problem for me.

If I had the WithRequired then the sql generated would be strange and it wouldn't return guids that were null e.g. guid = null. Returned an empty list even though the database has a few null guid values.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a standard identifier for the database. GUID? stored as a field in the table.

Comment: Please have a look at note mentioned in question 'by default Guid generate 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 for empty Guid which can grow database size'

Comment: You can't use nullable type for primary key. Use integer type for primary key and GUID? strored as a field in the table.